# problems with validation a datepickerfor from telerik

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, datepicker, telerik

so, heres whats happening, and what i want that happens..

i have a field defined

Object:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "field required")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:Y}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(c=> c.Date)            
              .Start(CalendarView.Year)
              .Depth(CalendarView.Year)
              .Format("{0:Y}")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
```

what happens here it that when i select a date what appears in the textbox is **"July, 2014"** that's exaclty what i want, 
but when i submit the form says.. **The field Date must be a date.**

I have tried already defining the object as a string instead a datetime, but then i cant associate the model to the datepicker..

resuming: objetive is having the field as required and as a datetime as printing in the textbox the "july 2014" or "july, 2014"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved the problem, dont know if its the best way.

What i did was changing the name of the datepicker

```
@Html.HiddenFor(c=>c.Date)
    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                  .Name("datepickerT")
                  .Start(CalendarView.Year)
                  .Depth(CalendarView.Year)
                  .Format("{0:Y}").Events(c=>c.change("change"))
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
<script> 

function change(){
$("#Date").val("01 " + $("#datepickerT").val());
}
</script>
```

i added the day 01 in the begining now its recognized as a date